# Searching Top Tweets Using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When I search tweets using Tweepy, I only get the latest tweets.

```
public_tweets = twitter.search_tweets('text to search', count=10, tweet_mode='extended')
```

I was wondering is there any way to get top tweets (first tab on mobile app) using its api?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information not just a single line of code, what version of Tweepy are you using? How have you instantiated the `twitter` object (this will dictate whether you are using Twitter API v1.1 or v2 - `search_tweets` is a v1.1 call though). Have you checked the [parameters in the documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets) which shows the types of search you can perform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `result_type` argument to `'popular'` to get only the top tweets.

```py
public_tweets = twitter.search_tweets('text to search', count=10, result_type='popular', tweet_mode='extended')
```

It is mixed between the top tweets and the more recent tweets by default.

For more information and to see the other possible values, you can read the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets).